# Number of ways to order n people into non-empty lines and then arrange these lines in a circle.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $g(n)$ be the number of ways to order n people into non-empty lines and then arrange these lines in a circle. Show that $g(n) = (2^n-1)(n-1)!$.

**My Attempt**: Let k $\le$ n be the number of lines. Then, $g(n) = SP(n, k) \times(k-1)!$ since there are $(k-1)!$ ways to arrange k lines into a circle, taking 1 of the k lines as a reference line. However, I do not have any idea where to go from here. The answer does not have the number of lines, $k$, in the function.

Comment: What does $~\color{red}{SP(n, k)}~$ signify?

Comment: It can't have $k$ in the function as that is not a parameter that is supplied.  You need to sum over all possible values of $k$ to answer the question.  I think you mean $k \le n$

Comment: @user2661923 I should have written that, it means the stirling number of 2nd kind, where n is the number of objects and k is the non-empty partitions.

Comment: @rossmillikan Yes, it should have been smaller or equal to sign. I thought maybe the terms would cancel each other, but that didn't happen. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: I would arrange the people in a circle and then cut the circle into lines.  I have a small difference from your formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RossMillikan has suggested:

There are $(n-1)!$ ways to arrange $n$ people into a circle. There are $2^n$ ways to divide these n people, since there are $n$ spaces between n people in a circle. 1 of the divisions will be no divisions, which means it's not a line, it's still a circle. So it's $g(n) = (2^n-1)(n-1)!$.